# how to close android app when back button pressed

Tags: android

I am building a simple login application on android platform.

The 1st Activity is a Login Activity and the 2nd one is a welcome screen.
When a user presses the login button, I start the 2nd Activity by using an Intent.
But in the 2nd Activity, when the user presses the back button, it opens the 1st Activity.
But at this point I want to close my app.

Can I use Fragments?
Any other alternative?

Comment: while calling welcome activity finsih the login activity.. so there won't be any backstack ...

Comment: Yes you can use fragment also. But considering your activity case , while switching from Activity A to B use finish()

Answer (score 1):

you have to just finish your activity when you switching another activity,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

you call the `finish()` in `LoginActivity` when you start the your `SecondActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

OR

you set the `android:noHistory = "true"` in `LoginActivity` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your second activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` from your first activity.

and then in your second activity you need to call `finish()` in `onbackpressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```